# How do I delay sending mails with PHPMailer for multiple days?

Tags: php, email, joomla, delay, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a mailing system for our library. People receive an e-mail when they requested a book. However, I want them to receive an e-mail one day before the hand-in date as well.

So I'm not looking for a sleep script code, I'm looking for a code that can maybe store the data on the server until the hand-in date arrived.

I'm using Joomla 3.5.1 for our website, this is the code for the PHPMailer:

```
jimport('joomla.mail.mail');

try{
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = $mailmsgadmin;

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "example.host.com";         // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                      // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                            // 1 = errors and messages
                                            // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                   // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "example.host.com";         // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "email"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "password";         // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('email', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo($mailuseremail, $mailusername);

$mail->Subject    = $mailsubject;

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress("Users e-mail","Users name");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  JError::raiseWarning( 'SOME_ERROR_CODE', $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
} catch (Exception $e) {JError::raiseWarning( 'SOME_ERROR_CODE', $e->getMessage());}
```

Comment: Your requests relate to books that are currently on loan?

Comment: If you do make a record of each request/reservation, then you could poll daily.  'All requests for books that are due tomorrow .'  For each request you could record the request date and the book key.  If the book isn't returned on time then it could be annoying.  Perhaps it would be better to only send out emails upon the books return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get PHPMailer delay the sending, add your email details to a database table. And then write a cron job that checks the table for emails that need to be sent.

Comment: Thanks! When requesting a book, the database automatically updates. I'll check out cron jobs tomorrow, wasn't expecting an answer this quick!